# "it is good" and "that is good"

Tags: difference, pronouns, demonstrative-pronouns

What is the difference between

> "it is good"

and

> "that is good"

?

Comment: It _would be_ good to have a little more context....

Answer (score 1):

By itself, I'd interpret ***it is good*** to mean ***all is well***.

However, I can't imagine myself saying it quite that way, although I might say, "**It's all good**" as an informal way of saying *It's alright:*

> I can't believe I broke the vase! I'm so sorry.
> **Response**: *It's all good – don't worry about it*.

In that case, "It's all good" essentially means: *I understand; it was an accident.*

---

As for ***that is good***, I'd probably say that as a contraction much more often than not: ***That's good***.

*That's good* is usually said as a reply to someone else. Because of the word *that*, some kind of context needs to be set, so the listener knows what the speaker is referring to. It often means something like, *good job,* or, *it sounds like things are going well so far*. For example:

> The lawnmower is almost fixed. I've put the new head gaskets in, and now I just need to put the carburetor back on.
>
> **Response**: *That's good. Why don't you wash up and eat dinner? I can help you finish up after we eat*.